# How to get Excel Pivot 'Summarize by' to return actual data values not sum, avg, etc?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, summarization

I am using Excel Powerpivot with data in two separate tables.  Table 1 has ITEM level data with a BRAND characteristic.  Table 2 has BRAND level data.  The two tables are linked by the BRAND key.  The measure I am using is non addable. i.e. the sum of the ITEMS does not equal the BRAND.  The pivot is set up with ITEMS nested under BRANDS in the rows and the Measure in the column.

Excel assumes that I want to summarize ITEM to a BRAND level by applying SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG, etc.  I would like to return the actual values from the appropriate ITEM or BRAND level table and not apply any calculations to the values.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give a very simple example of what your tables look like, and what you would like the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are effectively trying to do is produce a different result for the Brand rows (e.g. blank()) then the answer is to write a further measure that does a logic check to determine whether or not the row in question is an ITEM or a BRAND.

```
= IF (HASONEVALUE(table1[Item]), [Measure], Blank() )
```

Bear in mind that this will work for your current pivot but may not be adaptable to all pivots.

This assumes that you have explicitly created a measure called [Measure] and you are not just dragging the numeric column into the values box. If not you can create the initial [Measure] something like this:

```
= Sum(table1[Value])
```

Where Value is the column you want to use in the measure. Although you have used a sum, if it relates to a single item which has a single row in the table it will give the desired result.